# How can I measure two different source times and two different queue lengths in system in Any Logic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to build a fast-food simulation and I am having trouble measuring Queue length and average time in system. I was able to build out this same model in Cloudes (You can find the model here) and get the results I am looking for- but I can't seem to figure out why I am not getting any queue length in AnyLogic, and how to get time in system for each source.

The basic idea is someone comes in to the system, waits in a queue to order, places their order with a teller, goes back to wait for their food, picks up food, and then leaves the system. I have two different processes for each source, but both lead into the same kitchen. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, does anyone know how I run the simulation for a certain amount of replications and for a specific time period?

[Model image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eydh.png)

I added in the time measurement start and end, but it looks like it's not measuring the time correctly.

Comment: Please focus on one question per issue (i.e. ask the "how to run for repls and time periods" question separately, but obviously use the search first as these have been asked many times :) )

Comment: Also, some tips to ask great questions here, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can always collect queue length using `InPersonQueue.size()`, for example. Use code-complete to find all possible things you can do with a queue element.

For average time in system, place your TimeMeasure blocks correctly and pull the data from them as per the help.

(If you say "but it looks like it's not measuring the time correctly" then please provide details, they work 100% correct if you apply them correctly...)